# Solution of a congruence problem in number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was solving the following problem in number theory.

> Given integers $k,l$ relatively prime to integer $n>3$ such that $kl\equiv1\pmod {n}$,
>   where $n$ takes the form $n=4m,4m+1,4m+2$, and $4m+3$ for some positive integer $m$.

I was trying to find the value of $k$ for particular values of $l$ and $n$.

I assumed $l = 4$. Now, I need to find what values $k$ can attain to satisfy the above assumptions.

***My attempt:***

Since $l=4$ and it is relatively prime to $n$ then $n$ can not be $4m$ and $4m+2$.
In my first case I considered  $l=4$ and $n=4m+1$.

Now, since $k$ is relatively prime to $n$, $k$ will take values $4m$, $4m+2$, and few values of $4m+3$.

For example, I took the case where $l=4$, $n=4m+1$, and $k=4m$. This must satisfy $kl\equiv1\pmod {n}$. 
So I get

$$4(4m)\equiv1\pmod{(4m+1)}.$$

From here onwards, I am unable to proceed to solve and find the generalized value of **$k$ for $l=4$ only** for this problem. Can anyone help me in finding the solution? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak I need to find the value of $k$ for $l=4$ and $n=4m+1$ satisfying the congruence relation.

Comment: Try $k=9$. Have you tried the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Actually I am new to number theory.

Comment: If $k$ and $l$ are relatively prime, such that $k\cdot l\equiv 1\;\left(mod\;n\right)$, then
$k\equiv l^{\;\varphi\left(n\right)-1}\;\left(mod\;n\right)$ where $\varphi\left(n\right)$ is the [totient function][1].


  [1]: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html

Comment: @CleytonMuto You  mean to say that $kl\equiv l ^{\phi(n) -1}\pmod {n}$ is the solution set?

Comment: @monalisa exactly. When you multiply both sides of the congruence by the inverse multiplicative $l^{-1}$, then $l^{-1}\cdot\left(k\cdot l\right)\equiv l^{-1} \left(mod\;n\right)$; it means $k\equiv l^{-1}\left(mod\;n\right)$ and that's exactly the same as $k\equiv l^{\;\varphi\left(n\right)-1}\left(mod\;n\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $l = 4$, $(n, l) = 1$ requires that $2 \not\mid n$, i.e. $n \equiv 1, 3 \pmod{4}$. Because $(n, 4) = 1$, then$$
4k \equiv 1 \pmod{n} \Longrightarrow k \equiv \frac{1}{4} \equiv \frac{1 + an}{4} \pmod{n},
$$
where $a$ is an arbitrary integer. In particular,

1. If $n = 4m + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then$$
   0 \equiv 1 + an \equiv 1 + a \pmod{4} \Longrightarrow a \equiv -1 \equiv 3 \pmod{4},
   $$
   thus$$
   k \equiv \frac{1 + 3n}{4} \equiv 3m + 1 \pmod{n}.
   $$

   If $n = 4m + 3 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, then$$
   0 \equiv 1 + an \equiv 1 + 3a \pmod{4} \Longrightarrow a \equiv \frac{-1}{3} \equiv \frac{-1 + 4}{3} \equiv 1 \pmod{4},
   $$
   thus$$
   k \equiv \frac{1 + n}{4} \equiv m + 1 \pmod{n}.$$

Comment: +1. Look like a great answer to me. Examples
: 
$$n=13, k=10, 4 \times 10 = 40 = 1 \mod 13$$

$$n=19, k=5, 4 \times 5 = 20 = 1 \mod 19$$

Comment: Alex can you explain how you got the step $k \equiv \frac{1}{4} \equiv \frac{1 + an}{4} \pmod{n}$. Please .